# How can I remap a quick successive double press of the A key to function as a single press of the B key in any mode?

Tags: vim

I've tried `nnoremap aa b` in my .vimrc but it doesn't work. I want this to work in all modes (line mode, normal mode, and insert mode.)

Comment: Out of curiosity... why?

Comment: In my case, I plan to use it to replace `_` with `--` so that I stop typing `std::unique_Ptr<Char[]>` all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t know that you can do this with a single mapping (although that would probably be lovely), but the following series of three mode-specific mappings should do it:

```
nnoremap aa b
inoremap aa b
vnoremap aa b
```

Comment: what is noremap for? aren't you missing `nnoremap`?

Comment: And why the <Esc>? I want to insert b in the case i press aa in insert mode.

Comment: Oops — yes; I was trying something else and had left off the first `n` (for normal mode) at first. Also I thought that you wanted `b` the key whenever you entered `aa` in insert mode; the `<Esc>` and `i` were to briefly leave insert mode to enter `b` and then switch back. I fixed those both.